# Connecting PostGIS with GeoNetwork

Tags: postgis, geonetwork, configuration

I would like to connect a PostGIS-PostgreSQL database created in pgAdmin to GeoNetwork.

Which files in the webInf under the geonetwork folder I am supposed to modify and how?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `srv.xml` file at `...WEB-INF\config-node`:

Comment out the H2.xml config and uncomment the config that best suites your database.

```
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       default-lazy-init="true"
       xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
  <import resource="classpath*:/config-spring-geonetwork.xml"/>
  <import resource="../config-db/database_migration.xml"/>
  <!-- Uncomment the database configuration you need to use -->
  <!-- Default using the db.config.file if it exists and if not then derive the db file based on the db_type -->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/${geonetwork.db.type:h2}.xml"/> -->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/h2.xml"/> -->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/jndi-postgres-postgis.xml"/> -->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/oracle.xml"/>-->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/mysql.xml"/> -->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/db2.xml"/> -->
  <import resource="../config-db/postgres.xml"/>
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/sqlserver.xml"/> -->
  <!--<import resource="../config-db/postgres-postgis.xml"/>-->
</beans>
```

And in the `jdbc.properties` file at `WEB-INF\config-db`  You need to change the following parameter values:

```
jdbc.username=
jdbc.password=
jdbc.database=
jdbc.host=
jdbc.port=
```